# Not quite a Singleton

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, data-access-layer

I'm using ActionScript3 to develop a Data Access Layer for an application another developer is working on in my team. One of the objects, lets call it `User` is expensive to construct. Each user has a unique ID number so I can tell if they've been created before or not, and all `User` objects are stored in an array somewhere else.

I want to be able to restrict it so that there can be only once instance of a `User` per ID. I.E. each user has to be unique, and requests for an already constructed `User` should receive the pre-constructed `User`.

If I was using a sane, well-designed language I would simple make it a private constructor and force all requests for the object to go through a function that cached things. But flash doesn't allow private constructors (only public and internal, neither of which will work). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do the private construtor then you can achieve this like this:

```
package somepackage {
  public class User {
    public function User(SingletonEnforcer s):void {
      if (s == null)
        throw new Exception("Sorry mate!!!");
    }
    public static GetUserWithId(id:String):User {
      //user with this id exists then return it.
      //create a new user, initialize it, cache it and return
    }
  }
}
class SingletonEnforcer {
  //this is only visible to this class (User).
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary to store user ids mapped to User instances. This way you could check to see if there was already an existing user before creating a new one. Here is some pseudo code:

```
public class UserLookup()
{
    var _lookup:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    function getUser( id:int ):User 
    {
        if( _lookup[id] ) {
            return _lookup[id]
        } else {
            var user = new User( id );
            _lookup[ id ] = user;
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually did this and the accepted answer. I have a static function that creates the object, but it does a binary search on a static array that's sorted by ID.